# Query out data base on a list of id being parse in

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, oracle11g

So I got a list of ID being parse into my constructor. The job is to get the record that match with the ID from the list. So far I have tried:

```
 void displayChosenIDs(List<int> ids)
        {
            bool flag = false;


            List<Student> student_record = new List<Student>();

            //Display the interests IDs on grid
            using(StudentEntities context = new StudentEntities())
            {
                //get students correspond to ones in the list
                foreach(int value in ids)
                {
                    Student rec =  (Student)(from o in context.Students
                                    where o.ID.CompareTo(value) == 0
                                    select o);
                    student_record.Add(rec);
                }
}
```

I get an error saying unable to type cast using my linq and type cast to student. Is there another way to do this using linq without a need for foreach()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an `InvalidCastException` because select returns an `IQueryable<Student>`, not a single `Student`. You could achieve what you want in one line using `Where` and `Contains` :

```
student_record.AddRange(context.Students.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)));

// Or:
var student_record = context.Students.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: I have a Form1_load event in my code. What if I want the above code running from the instructor instead of running from the Form1_Load() what should I do?